# Are there any good APIs for maintaining an open connection between Flash <--> Java

Tags: java, flash, network-programming

I have a flash app which will send/receive a constant stream of data.

the flash app should open a connection to the Java server, keep it open, and attempt to reconnect on socket failure.

Are there any good APIs that offer this functionality? Smartfox Server is one option, but if I had my way I'd embed an API in my app rather than contort my app to run under Smartfox.

Ideally it would offer an API on the flash end, another on the Java end, and efficiently (java nio preferably) handle the network component in between. I would just define handlers on both the client & server.

Comment: I'm not sure this is relevant to your situation, so I make it a comment rather than an answer, but there is an ActionScript API for socket communication http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/flash/net/Socket.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [BlazeDS](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/blazeds/BlazeDS). It's an open source RTMP server from Adobe written in Java. You don't need any special library on the client side as RTMP is native in Flash.

There are many examples on the web: [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/blazeds/1/blazeds_devguide/help.html?content=lcoverview_4.html) , [here](http://codeofdoom.com/wordpress/2009/02/01/blazeds-with-remote-objects-example/).